# Eclipse Indigo C++ project settings

Tags: eclipse, preprocessor, project-settings

I created a C++ shared library project in Ubuntu with compiler **g++ 4.6**.
Some of the dependency libraries expects some **preprocessor commands** about compiler and operating system to properly compile, like

```
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__llvm__) || defined(__clang__)
```

However **Eclipse** doesn't define them automatically (at least the version I'm using), is there a setting or option in Eclipse which does this for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set preprocessor defines in the project properties: [image: project properties].

However, in your case, I wouldn't use these, as they shouldn't be project specific (due to them being compiler specific). I actually think you're looking for these. I'm not sure for llvm/clang (there are ones, but I don't remember them right now), but for GCC you should use the macro `__GNUC__` which will be defined by the compiler itself, without you having to worry about it. The leading underscores tell you, that they aren't part of the standard and not necessarily defined when using another compiler (e.g. MSVC).

---

For cross platform usage of `vsprintf_s`:

```
// this will be set on Visual Studio only, so this code is added for all other compilers
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#define vsprintf_s(b,l,f,v) vsprintf(b,f,v);
#endif
```

But in general, try to use functions that are available on all platforms (for this example, in this case use `vsnprintf()` instead).

Comment: my project try to use vsprintf_s this function which is a microsoft implementation, however eclipse doesn't add any preprocessor command automatically, and I don't want to add them manually. as a result, I end up with this compiler error: "glm/core/.././gtx/string_cast.inl:26:30: error: ‘vsprintf_s’ was not declared in this scope" Just because I didn't set up dependency library properly. Here is the link to my setup file http://glm.g-truc.net/api-0.9.0/a00076_source.html

Comment: I also wanted to add this:
 /* echo "" | g++ -E -dM -x c++ - | sort */ 
when you write this command to console, it shows preprocessor commands defined automatically by the compiler as Mario said. I believe my source of error is something else then preprocessor commands.

Comment: The standard functions with a `_s` postfix are MSVC only additions to make them more save against buffer overruns. Just add some simple "compatibility defines" to a header file (I'll add a short example above).